# Function with variable arguments

Tags: function-construction

I wrote a function with three arguments like this

```
f[a_,b_,c_]:=...
```

When I call this function MMA requires the input of all three arguments (e.g. f[1,2,3]).

Is there a possibility to define the argument c_ as "varaible" that I can call the function with two (e.g. f[1,2]) or three (e.g. f[1,2,3] arguments?

Comment: See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) and note that the lhs of `:=` is really just a pattern and you can have "definitions" for as many patterns as you like.  `f[1]=2; f[a_,b_]=3; f[x_,y_,z_]:=x`

Comment: You can also define a default value for `c`. For example, `f[a_, b_, c_:3] := {a, b, c}`. Then `f[1, 2, 42]` gives `{1, 2, 42}` and `f[1, 2]` gives `{1, 2, 3}`.